# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type (Model class)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried so hard but I Can't convert an object of type `java.lang.Long` to type (My Model class).

I am uploading my `getDataFromFirebase()` method below:

***MainActivity.class***

```
private void getDataFromFirebase() {
        binding.projectRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        binding.projectRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
        binding.projectRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter = new ProjectAdapter(activity,projectDetailsBeanList);

        projectDetailsBeanList = new ArrayList<>();

        firebaseDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("project_details");

        DBListener = databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                projectDetailsBeanList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    ProjectModel.ProjectDetailsBean projectDetailsBean = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProjectModel.ProjectDetailsBean.class);
                    projectDetailsBean.setKey(snapshot.getKey());
                    projectDetailsBeanList.add(projectDetailsBean);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

---

***My Model Class***

```
public class ProjectModel {

    private ProjectDetailsBean project_details;

    public ProjectDetailsBean getProject_details() {
        return project_details;
    }

    public void setProject_details(ProjectDetailsBean project_details) {
        this.project_details = project_details;
    }


    public static class ProjectDetailsBean {

        private int architect_no;
        private String client_name;
        private String payment_received;
        private String project_complete_date;
        private String project_name;
        private int project_no;
        private String project_received_date;
        private String key;

        @Exclude
        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Exclude
        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public int getArchitect_no() {
            return architect_no;
        }

        public void setArchitect_no(int architect_no) {
            this.architect_no = architect_no;
        }

        public String getClient_name() {
            return client_name;
        }

        public void setClient_name(String client_name) {
            this.client_name = client_name;
        }

        public String getPayment_received() {
            return payment_received;
        }

        public void setPayment_received(String payment_received) {
            this.payment_received = payment_received;
        }

        public String getProject_complete_date() {
            return project_complete_date;
        }

        public void setProject_complete_date(String project_complete_date) {
            this.project_complete_date = project_complete_date;
        }

        public String getProject_name() {
            return project_name;
        }

        public void setProject_name(String project_name) {
            this.project_name = project_name;
        }

        public int getProject_no() {
            return project_no;
        }

        public void setProject_no(int project_no) {
            this.project_no = project_no;
        }

        public String getProject_received_date() {
            return project_received_date;
        }

        public void setProject_received_date(String project_received_date) {
            this.project_received_date = project_received_date;
        }
    }
}
```

---

***JSON data***

```
{
  "project_details" : {
    "architect_no" : 1,
    "client_name" : "pratik bharad",
    "payment_received" : "yes",
    "project_complete_date" : "22/09/2020",
    "project_name" : "project of building",
    "project_no" : 1,
    "project_received_date" : "22/06/2020"
  }
}
```

Error is:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.psb.aurumdesign.ProjectModel$ProjectDetailsBean

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JSON at `project_details` that is failing (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.psb.aurumdesign.ProjectModel$ProjectDetailsBean

Because you are trying to convert the first child from your `project_details` node which is of type Long into an object of type `ProjectDetailsBean`, which is actually not possible. As I see in the JSON schema, under the `project_details` node, there is actually a single object, so there is no need to actually loop through the children in order to get the data. You can simply map that object directly into an object of type `ProjectDetailsBean`, as in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference projectDetailsRef = rootRef.child("project_details");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ProjectDetailsBean projectDetailsBean = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProjectDetailsBean.class);
        Log.d("TAG", projectDetailsBean.getProject_name());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
projectDetailsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be the name of the project. If you only need, for example, the value of a single property, you can change the following line of code:

```
ProjectDetailsBean projectDetailsBean = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProjectDetailsBean.class);
```

To:

```
String projectName = dataSnapshot.child("project_name").getValue(String.class);
```